# android gradle Received invalid response from the daemon

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, atlassian-sourcetree

My project gradle is in building situation on the other hand i pushed the code on bitbucket after pushing when i come back to android studio this error comes

> Error:Received invalid response from the daemon: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.ForwardInput@225d8c3e is a result
>   of a type we don't have a strategy to handle. Earlier,
>   'Build{id=64d7a5e0-2e12-4d52-950f-6540c826a70b.1,
>   currentDir=C:\Users\Project Directory}' request was sent to the
>   daemon. Diagnostics:
>           No diagnostics available.

Sometimes come this Error

> Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: i got the solution of this issue. Just delete the .gradle folder from your project repository and build in again your problem resolved.
i hope its help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this issue. Just ***delete*** the

```
.gradle
```

folder from your project repository and ***build*** in again your problem resolved. 
*I hope it helps others.*

Answer (score 1):

1.Shutdown your Machine(Computer,System) and start again.
this step work for me hope affected in your case.
[gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle)  [androidstudio](/questions/tagged/androidstudio) [gradleissue](/questions/tagged/gradleissue)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the gradle file inside the project folder, Then built it again, Then it downloaded a file called gradle-4.4-bin.zip, Then it built succesfuly, I think you are missing the gradle-bin, This way you can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file 'registry.bin.lock' under the location '.gradle\daemon\2.14.1\' resolved the issue for me without having to have restart intelliJ or system